# Почему ни один из моих проектов не видит" [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]"

Tags: spring, mvc, glassfish

Доброго всем дня. Ситуация следующая, сделал минипроект по примеру, стал запускать, вывалилась ошибка Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml], думал может где что не правильно написал, и загрузил исходник автора курса, та же проблема. Потом уже просто стал с нуля создавать проект (в IDEA) там есть возможность поставить в проекте, add framework support, она сама создает все папки,и файл index.jsp я лишь указываю сервер, а именно glassfish-4.1.1 потом запускаю и опять та же проблема.

Содержание файла web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Напишите минимально вопроизводимый пример и прикрепите его в тело вопроса. В текущем виде больше похоже на "сделайте за меня" (с этим на биржи фриланса отправляют) и ваш вопрос без этой информации не принесёт никакой пользы другим посетителям сайта.

Comment: У меня ссылка на гит прикреплена, да и примера то особо ни какого нет, куча стандартных файлов для web проекта, типа "applicationContext.xml" и ему подобных, не писать же мне еще и сюда их содержание.

Comment: Ради интереса отмотайте вопросы прошлого года и посмотрите, сколько из них содержат "выложил в дропбокс мой проект" и "вот ссылка на мой гитхаб" -- сколько из них ещё работает. Сделать минимальный рабочий пример -- это ваша работа, как автора вопроса, вы её хотите переложить на других: прошерстите весь мой репозиторий, найдите ошибку. Чем это отличается от вопросов "сделайте за меня домашнюю работу", которых тут полно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не вставляйте код картинками или в комментарии: он становится нечитаемым. Если вы хотите привести код -- ниже поста есть кнопка "править", а в ней - инструменты оформления кода.

Comment: Минус на вопрос за плохое оформление кода. Поправите -- сниму.

Comment: @AK Подскажите если не секрет как вставить xml? Если у меня есть возможность вставить только код и HTML, а у меня ни HTML ни строчки кода нет так как проект на Spring, а xml выглядит не красиво.

Comment: Как вставить код на любом языке. Пишете текст, потом отбиваете одну пустую строку, вставляете свой код. Выделяете мышкой фрагмент кода и нажимаете кнопку {} на панели инструментов или сочетание клавиш Ctrl+K. Готово. Пример -- в вашем посте. Минус снимаю, но вы лучше потренируйтесь, чтобы потом сразу пачку не поймать.